# Construction of a special unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a  $4 \times4$ matrix with complex entries with columns and rows are mutually orthogonal and row/column vectors have norm $\sqrt{2}$ where the the rows and columns are indexed by $(i,j)$, $i,j=1,2$ such that if you put any column/row of $A$ into a $2 \times 2$ matrix will be unitary. From $A$ I want to construct another matrix $B$ which has the following property.Columns /rows are mutually orthogonal and each has norm $\sqrt{2}$ and if we take any two columns indexed by (-,j). From these take the rows indexed by (i,-). The resultant $2 \times 2$ matrix should be unitary. How can we get $B$ from $A$? Please help me. By which matrix we should apply to $A$ to get $B$?
That is explicitely I have the following data.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a^{11}_{11} & a^{11}_{12} & a^{11}_{21} &   a^{11}_{22} \\
    a^{12}_{11} & a^{12}_{12} & a^{12}_{21} &   a^{12}_{22} \\
    a^{21}_{11} & a^{21}_{12} & a^{21}_{21} &   a^{21}_{22} \\
   a^{22}_{11} & a^{22}_{12} & a^{22}_{21} &   a^{22}_{22}  
\end{bmatrix}
$
and I have the following matrices are unitary.

$C_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{11} & a^{21}_{11}\\
 a^{12}_{11} & a^{22}_{11}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{12} & a^{21}_{12}\\
 a^{12}_{12} & a^{22}_{12}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{21}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{21} & a^{21}_{21}\\
 a^{12}_{21} & a^{22}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{22} & a^{21}_{22}\\
 a^{12}_{22} & a^{22}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$

I need to construct a $B$ from $A$ having the following property.
If $B=\begin{bmatrix}
    b^{11}_{11} & b^{11}_{12} & b^{11}_{21} &   b^{11}_{22} \\
    b^{12}_{11} & b^{12}_{12} & b^{12}_{21} &   b^{12}_{22} \\
    b^{21}_{11} & b^{21}_{12} & b^{21}_{21} &   b^{21}_{22} \\
   b^{22}_{11} & b^{22}_{12} & b^{22}_{21} &   b^{22}_{22}  
\end{bmatrix}
$ Then $B$ should satisfy the following conditions.

1. $B$ should have mutually orthogonal rows and columns with norm being $\sqrt{2}$
2. The following matrices formed from $B$ are unitary.

$D_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{11}_{11} & b^{11}_{21}\\
 b^{12}_{11} & b^{12}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{11}_{12} & b^{11}_{22}\\
 b^{12}_{12} & b^{12}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{21}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{21}_{11} & b^{21}_{21}\\
 b^{22}_{11} & b^{22}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{21}_{12} & b^{21}_{22}\\
 b^{22}_{12} & b^{22}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$
Is there any way to construct $B$ using $A$?
If $A$ has only real entries, there is a solution which is $H \otimes I_2$ where $H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1\\
 1 & -1
 \end{bmatrix}$. If you multiply $A$ with $H \otimes I_2$ then will get a matrix with properties as that of $B$. I am not able to proceed into complex entries. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand your comment at the end.  Are you trying to say that $H \otimes I_2$ is an example of a suitable matrix $B$?

Comment: Also: is there any purpose/motivation for this exercise?

Comment: No if you multiply A with $H \otimes I_2$ you will get a matrix with properties as that of $B$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it is related to some planar algebra work. These types of matrices will arise there. I want to connect those.

Comment: ...and you're saying that this trick works when $A$ is a (suitable) matrix of real entries, but fails when the entries are complex?  I find that extremely surprising.  Where does it go wrong in the complex case?

Comment: If you do this column orthogonality will follow. But while proving the unitarity of the special $2 \times 2$ sub matrices will involve terms  for example like $a\overline{b}-b\overline{a}$ which is zero if the matrix $A$ is real.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60357/discussion-between-anupam-ah-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: I would guess that you can find an $\tilde H(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ such that $B = A \tilde H(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ satisfies the necessary condition, where we take
$$
\tilde H(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) = 
\pmatrix{e^{i \theta_3} & e^{i \theta_3}\\1 & -1} \otimes \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \pmatrix{e^{i \theta_1} & 0\\ 0 & e^{i \theta_2}} 
$$

Comment: I am confused of $\tilde{H}$ and $H$. You mean only $H$ in the above comment right?

Comment: I am referring to only one matrix.  I'm using $\tilde H$ to make it different from your $H$.

Comment: Fine..... Thanks...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have added the reference in the case of orthogonal matrices

Comment: Okay, I'll probably take a look tomorrow

Comment: Okay thanks....

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Did you look at it?